Container works locally but not on Google Cloud Run
I have a Node.js app and an Angular app. I've dockerized them. They run in the same container. Nginx serves the Angular app and sends the /api/* requests to the Node.js server.
It works perfectly when I'm running the container on my local machine. But it doesn't work on Google Cloud Run. More specifically, I get 502 errors when calling the API endpoints.
I can see this in the GCP logs:

connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: , request: "GET /api/ping HTTP/1.1"

My Dockerfile:
FROM node:20

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci --omit=dev

RUN cd my-project && npm i && npm run build && cd ..

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN cp -r ./my-project/dist/my-project/browser/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
 
CMD npm run pm2:start:prod && nginx -g 'daemon off;'


And the Nginx config:
user  root;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name _;

        # Serve static files from the /usr/share/nginx/html directory
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Proxy requests to /api to the backend server
        location /api/ {
            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        }

        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stderr;
    }
}

Interestingly, it used to work without Nginx and with ng serve that used to proxy requests itself.

Why do not using side car? It's a better pattern for this use case!

Can you change port from 8080 to 80 in your ngnix.config file? Also have a look at these links: link1 and link 2

@guillaumeblaquiere I may try sidecar - it looks like a better approach than having multiple processes in the same container.

@RoopaM why would it be necessary? Cloud Run exposes 8080 by default.

The nginx base image is tricky because it does EXPOSE 80, but your nginx.conf is listening to 8080. Cloud Run will use the EXPOSE'd port to try to connect to your application.

@MikeBorozdin, Have you managed to check above comment? Does it help you solve your issue? Or have you found any other solution?
